# Send private message with discordgo

Tags: go, discord

I would like to have a discord bot reply to a message made in a public channel via a private message.

I am able to detect whether a channel is private or not using the following code from the [FAQ](https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/wiki/FAQ#checking-if-a-message-is-from-a-private-channel):

```
func isTheChannelTheMessageWasSentInPrivate(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
    channel, err := s.State.Channel(m.ChannelID)
    if err != nil {
        astilog.Fatal(err)
        return
    } else if m.Author.ID == s.State.User.ID {
        return
    }
    channelIsPrivate := strconv.FormatBool(channel.IsPrivate)
    print("Channel ID: " + m.ChannelID + ". Is it private? " + channelIsPrivate + "\n")
}
```

And I can reply to a message on the same channel it was received using this code:

```
func recieveMessage(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
    s.ChannelMessageSend(m.ChannelID, "Reply!")
}
```

But I can't figure our how to get the `ChannelID` of a user's direct message channel from the [`Message`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Message) object that is available upon receiving a message.

Comment: I think this is a bit confusing, maybe it's just me.  It seems like you already know how to the get the ChannelID from the Message object. `Message.ChannelID`

Comment: `Message.ChannelID` is the public channel the message was sent on. I would like to reply to the private channel of the user who sent the message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The session struct has a method `UserChannelCreate(recipientID string)`, which returns the DM channel for given userID. Don't mind the 'Create', if a DM channel already exists, it will be reused.